# Is the Url Encoded value(s) for a Get method passed as RequestHeader?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I have a get request with a huge data being passed as urlencoded values. As a result of that I get HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

I found that the Azure server which accepts the requests has some limits set which i can't modify. So, I'm planing to make the get request POST so that my values will be sent as part of body and not the headers.

I am sure that if we make a post request, the data is sent in the body (not the header). What I am not sure is whether i can do the same with get request.

PS: To query some data, some data (huge) data is being passed, so this is a get operation. The code was written by someone else, I'm trying to fix the issue now.

Comment: You should not submit data using `GET`. Always use `POST` to submit anything, regardless of how small it is. `GET` is for fetching data... not sending. Anyway, `GET` is limited to about 2000 characters... that is the general limit of how long URL can be, beyond that... you are in uncharted territory.

Comment: @RosdiKasim I am not submitting any data. Actually it is a query (get operation). To fetch some data, some data is being passed. The data being passed is huge. So, I'm planing to go unconventional by using post for get operation - Don't know if this is correct.

Comment: That's weird, why would you have such a huge query... perhaps a redesign is in order? I could not think of a scenario where I will have a huge `GET` query.

Comment: @RamVenkat Post method to post data instead of Get method is actually not unconventional. That is the right approach. You can post the Ids of the data instead of the actual data? This will reduce the Url length if you have to use Get.